# Being prompted for '(null)' GNOME keyring

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Whenever I try interacting with an SVN server, ubuntu prompts me for the password to a '(null)' keyring. I don't have a keyring called this, so I'm assuming that some code somewhere is actually encountering a null value. I haven't even set up any keyrings, so I don't know why I'm getting prompted for one. I've entered in every password I've ever used for anything on that machine, and nothing works.

How can I get it so (a) keyring works or (b) svn stops asking for it?

I've tried setting up my ~/.subversion/config to explicitly use gnome-keyring, and I've tried 'store-auth-creds=no' and neither works.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On a whim, I deleted ~/.gnome2/keyrings/* and now it works!

Comment: It deletes all keyrings, including (default). And by 'works' I think I meant that it prompted me to create a new keyring with a new passphrase, which I then had to add all of my accounts to.

Comment: Beware you might be removing more passwords than you intend! gnome-keyring is made for keeping possibly all your passwords.

Answer (score 26):

This is enough for me:

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring
```